# R: confusion about the example of function .bincode

Tags: r, radix

The `.bincode()` function of the `base` package in R confuses me in one of it's example.
Here is the confusing example.

1. Create a list of data for test.

```
x <- c(0, 0.01, 0.5, 0.99, 1)
b <- c(0, 0, 1, 1)
```

2. Here comes the confusion.

```
.bincode(x, b, FALSE)
```

It returens with `2  2  2  2 NA`.
But according to the usage, `.bincode(x, breaks, right = TRUE, include.lowest = FALSE)`, `.bincode(x, b, FALSE)` equals to `.bincode(x, b, right = FALSE, include.lowest = FALSE)`,
then the division interval should be: (-Inf, 0), [0, 1), [1, +Inf), which means the `x` should be mapped into `NA, 2, 2, 2, 3`.

The **inconsistency between inference and R output** confuses me a lot.

Comment: The Detail section in the documentation of the function explains this: "Unlike cut, the breaks do not need to be unique. An input can only fall into a zero-length interval if it is closed at both ends, so only if include.lowest = TRUE and it is the first (or last for right = FALSE) interval."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misreading the documentation.  As I read it, it says the bins should be

```
empty, [0, 1), empty
```

because "An input can only fall into a zero-length interval if it is closed at both ends, so only if include.lowest = TRUE and it is the first (or last for right = FALSE) interval."  Since you have `include.lowest = FALSE`, nothing can fall in your 0,0 or 1,1 intervals, so they are empty.  Everything except 1 falls in the middle bin (bin 2); 1 falls in no bin, so it gets NA.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I presume that beyond the first `0` and last `1`, there will be (-/+) infinite. Now I get the logic of the function. Thank you so much.